# Visual Studio C++ Optimizing compiled disassembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, reverse-engineering, disassembly

Recently, I was creating some tasks for reverse engineering on C++. I understood I know nothing about the compiler workflow and how to use it properly. Usually, I was using Visual Studio for C++ and never tried to reverse it and read my own functions. However, I need to create a program that is quiet easy to read after disassembly and I wanted to teach other to reverse engineer based on my own code, that would be safe and etc.

How can I compile the code without lots of "junk"? Like security cookies, debugging info, lots of functions (that I didn't actually used). I was reversing many "crackme's" in the past and they were quite readable, so I hope i can create something similar. Is there any way to control the program's flow manually?

Comment: there is an community dedicated to reverse engineering - https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ . I think this question is on-topic here but you probably would get good answers there as well. You probably could use old compilers to generate crackmes

Comment: In Microsoft Visual Studio, make sure you always use release builds instead of debug builds. That way, unused functions will be optimized away and there will be no extra debugging checks or debugging info.

Comment: Read the disassembly. Find something you don't like. Turn off that feature of the compiler, in the project options. Rinse and repeat.